# How do I prevent leaking credentials between two different users with java.net.Authenticator without using private API?

Tags: java, authentication

Java 9 is going to finally stop us using sun internal classes.

One such usages we still have is the following:

```
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.AuthCache;
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.AuthCacheValue;

public static void authenticationHacks() {
    AuthCacheValue.setAuthCache(new NullAuthCache());
}

//...

class NullAuthCache implements AuthCache {
    @Override
    public void put(String s, AuthCacheValue authCacheValue) {
    }

    @Override
    public AuthCacheValue get(String s, String s1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(String s, AuthCacheValue authCacheValue) {
    }
}
```

Is there a public replacement for this?

As far as the X of the X-Y problem, this is a workaround for multiple users running in a single application where that application makes requests using `java.net.URL`. If you don't perform this hack, the credentials for the first successfully-authenticated user will be kept around and passed to other servers for requests which actually belong to different users.

If there is another way to do that, I'd like to know. I gather that this was a bug in the JRE, so if they have fixed it since, that would be good to know as well.

As an example of the problem at hand, using only the publicly available API, you run into the following problem:

```
public class AuthenticationLeakBugDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // User 1
        {
            System.out.println("Simulating user 1 coming in " +
                "without authentication at first.");
            System.out.println("Expecting: 401");
            URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/a/a");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
                url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("Got: " + connection.getResponseCode());
        }

        // User 1
        {
            System.out.println("Simulating user 1 coming in " +
                "with proper authentication.");
            System.out.println("Expecting: 200");
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("a", "a".toCharArray());
                }
            });
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/a/a");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                System.out.println("Got: " + connection.getResponseCode());
            } finally {
                Authenticator.setDefault(null);
            }
        }

        // User 2
        {
            System.out.println("Simulating user 2 coming in with no authentication.");
            System.out.println("Expecting: 401");
            URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/a/a");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("Got: " + connection.getResponseCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Output is of course:

```
Simulating user 1 coming in without authentication at first.
Expecting: 401
Got: 401
Simulating user 1 coming in with proper authentication.
Expecting: 200
Got: 200
Simulating user 2 coming in with no authentication.
Expecting: 401
Got: 200
```

Indicating that Java's internal authentication cache has leaked one user's credentials to another user. :(

Comment: you got any solution for this ?

Comment: We ended up moving to the client in Commons HTTP, but we still have our code around using AuthCache as I'm still unaware of a public alternative.

Comment: In jdk 9 onwards no support for AuthCache

Comment: Exactly, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Any solution or alternative found for this.  Since we use jdk 11 I am unable to use AuthCache from sun @RajavelD

Comment: @Raj avoid using `java.net.URL` basically. Java has java.net.http now, which might work. We switched to Commons HTTP, like mentioned in a previous comment.